# What is the aviation term for what the navy calls "fire control system"?

Tags: military, terminology

The weapons systems, including computers etc, in a naval ship can be referred to as the Fire Control System. I'm not sure if FCS would be considered an appropriate acronym for fire control; I'm using to hearing FCS as Flight Control System.

Is there a specific aviation term equivalent to Fire Control System? If so, what acronym does it use (if any)?

Comment: The answer to this would depend on which armed aircraft one is flying.  Are you specifically asking about the system the is integrated with a gun, with missile systems, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still called the (Airborne) Fire Control System; found about it [here](https://pe.gatech.edu/courses/basic-airborne-fire-control-systems) from a Google search.

Well, the acronym for (Airborne) Fire Control System is FCS (As well as Flight Control System) according to [a military acronym website](http://www.militaryacronyms.net/f)

Comment: @sanchises Fixed it.

Comment: When searching for 'aircraft fire control system' on Google I was mostly getting results for Anti-Aircraft Fire Control Systems on naval vessels, but being more thorough now I see that there are some sources that refer to the weapon systems on aircraft as a Fire Control System as well. That does still leave the other part of the question unanswered - is there an acronym for Fire Control System? The obvious one would be FCS but that would conflict with Flight Control System